# Not Getting the required Elasticity as per the formula designed

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    float x[5] = { 60, 61, 62, 63, 65 }, y[5] = { 31, 36, 38, 40, 41 };
    int i, Elasticity;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Elasticity = ((y[i + 1] - y[i]) / y[i]) / ((x[i + 1] - x[i]) / x[i]);
        printf("Elasticity is %d",Elasticity);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to print elasticity values per the formula designed, but I am getting the wrong values. For example, for first case I should get
Elasticity = ((36 - 31) / 31) / ((61 - 60) / 60) =  9.677 (approx.)

What has to be done?

Comment: You still have out of bounds array indexing as [previously commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444089/expected-expression-before-error-is-showing#comment95697481_54444089).

Comment: When `i` is 4 (at the last iteration), `y[i + 1]` is an out-of-bound access.

Answer (score 3):

Three things:

1. `Elasticity` is of type `int`. It cannot contain fractional parts. You need to make it a `float`, `double` or `long double` for it to be able to contain a fractional part.
2. You are using the `%d` format specifier in your `printf` call, which is intended to print out a signed integer in base-10. Use `%f` to print out a `float` or `double`.
3. As commenter @user58697 pointed out, you are performing an out of bounds access on `y[i + 1]` on the last iteration of your `for` loop. I'm not sure what your intent is with your calculation, so I cannot offer a solution for it.